# Dataframe size increases after saving to .h5 the first time

Tags: pandas, hdf5

A pandas dataframe file size increases significantly after saving it as `.h5` the first time. If I save loaded dataframe, the file size doesn't increase again. It makes me suspect that some kind of meta-data is being saved the first time. What is it the reason for this crease?

Is there an easy way to avoid it?

I can compress the file but I am making comparisons without compression. Would the problem scale differently with compression?

Example code below. The file size increases from `15.3 MB` to `22.9 MB`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.random.normal (0,1, 1000000)
y = x*2
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': x, 'Column2': y})
print (dataset.info(memory_usage='deep'))
dataset.to_hdf('data.h5', key='df', mode='w')
dataset2 = pd.read_hdf("data.h5")
print (dataset2.info(memory_usage='deep'))
dataset2.to_hdf('data2.h5', key='df', mode='w')
dataset3 = pd.read_hdf("data2.h5")
print (dataset3.info(memory_usage='deep'))
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Column1    1000000 non-null float64
Column2    1000000 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 15.3 MB
None
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Column1    1000000 non-null float64
Column2    1000000 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 22.9 MB
None
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Column1    1000000 non-null float64
Column2    1000000 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 22.9 MB
None
```

It is happening because `RangeIndex` is converted to `Int64Index` on save. Is there a way to optimise this ? Looks like there's no way to drop the index:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8319

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found till now is to save as pickle:

```
dataset.to_pickle("datapkl.pkl")
```

less convenient option is to convert to numpy and save with `h5py`, but then loading and converting back to pandas takes a lot of time

```
a = dataset.to_numpy()
h5f = h5py.File('datah5.h5', 'w')
h5f.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=a)
```